# Minification of ES6 javascript files Bundle - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ecmascript-6, bundling-and-minification

I'm using a ASP.NET Application and I'm using the new ES6 syntax on my javascript files. Also, I'm using the `ScriptBundle` to organize and minify my javascript files.

**Problem:**

The problem is that the files are not being minifyed and I think the problem is because of the ES6 syntax because in the javascript files that I don't use ES6 syntax the files are being minifyed well.

**Code Extract:**

```
 /* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
 (91577,1-6): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: class
    (91578,12-21): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': importLib
    (91578,25-26): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': {
    (91609,1-2): run-time error JS1002: Syntax error: }
    (91613,12-21): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': importLib
    (91613,25-26): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': {
    (91627,1-2): run-time error JS1002: Syntax error: }
    (91631,12-21): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': importLib
    (91631,24-25): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': {
    (91645,1-2): run-time error JS1002: Syntax error: }
     */
    class FacebookLib {
    static importLib () {
        if (!HelperJSViewBag.getValue("OSPIntegration")) {
            try {
                window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                    FB.init({
                        appId: HelperJSViewBag.getValue("facebookID"),
                        cookie: true,
                        xfbml: true,
                        version: 'v2.5'
                    });
                };

                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + HelperJSViewBag.getValue("Language") + "/sdk.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }
                    (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            } catch (ex) {
                new Exception({
                    className: "ImportingFacebookLibrary",
                    exception: ex,
                    errors: true,
                    warnMessage: "warn: importing facebook library"
                });
            }
        }

    }
}

;
class DropboxLib {
    static importLib () {
        new Ajax().importScripts({
            url: "https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js",
            insucess: function (data) {
                new Exception({
                    className: "ImportingDropboxLib",
                    exception: ex,
                    errors: true,
                    warnMessage: "warn: importing dropbox library"
                });
            },
            async: true
        });
    }
}

;
class GoogleLib {
    static importLib() {
        new Ajax().importScripts({
            url: "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js",
            insucess: function (data) {
                new Exception({
                    className: "ImportingGoogleLib",
                    exception: ex,
                    errors: true,
                    warnMessage: "warn: importing google library"
                });
            },
            async: true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using any transpiler before the bundling? ES6 code will not run in browser

Comment: Typically ES6 is compiled using something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/). It's not well supported currently. I'd imagine the minification in MVC has no idea what any of this means. i.e. it doesn't support ES6

Comment: **Some** of it will work in **some** browsers @Niladri. But your right, ES6 will likely require a transpiler.

Comment: @Niladri My code in google chrome is working perfectly. In other browser I'm not sure. Also, I not that in mobile the es6 is not implemented very well. But my problem is only the minifycation. I'm supposing there is a way that ASP.net could minify es6 javascript files, like activate a option or something. If not, I will be forced to transpile the files before put them on the bundle.

Comment: @RicardoRocha google chrome has this feature of enabling experimental javascript (with caution that may be break pages) so it will work on Chrome but to be on safe side you need to use Babel or Traceur js to transpile it . As of my understanding .NET MVC only bundles js image and css files as you provide them without any traspile .So better convert it to ES5 before bundling

Comment: else you can use Typescript which automatically converted to js on compilation

Comment: @Niladri I understand. But I already started my project, and it will be hard migrate to typescript

Comment: @RicardoRocha Valid ES6 should be valid TypeScript, so it may be less problematic than you expect. If not TS then you're going to need either Babel or a minifier that understands ES6 syntax.

Comment: if you are using ES6 then you can just create a ts file with the same code with minimum changes , then you store the the compiled js file in a folder and bundle them. you just need one tsconfig and gulp file if required